# Show a loading gif while waiting getJSON

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to display a loading GIF while I wait for the getJSON to return the results.

I'm using the $("#loader").hide() and $("#loader").show() events but with no luck.

```
@{
<style>
    #loader {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 10000;
    }
</style>

<div class="loader" style="display:none;">
    <img src="~/Images/loadingAnim.gif" width="208" height="13"/>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ID").change(function () {
            //some code
            $("#loader").show();
            $.getJSON(url, { //more code});
            $("#loader").hide();
        })
    })
</script>
}
```

When the ID ddl changes, I do not see the GIF.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i dont know what you mean with `#ID`, as i cant see an element with that id the code provided by you.

Down below you can see some modified code, what I did was changing the `#loader` to `.loader` because the HTML loading element has a loader class not an id. If you want to target an ID you should use the property `id="loader"` on your element.

Also I removed the width, height and `display: none` styles of your html element as this is not needed. You can specify all these props in your class. But dont specify your display property at all.

You can hide the element via javascript as you can see down below in the HTML, Javascript and CSS.

```
<div class="loader" >
    <img src="~/Images/loadingAnim.gif"/>
</div>
<button id="btn">Load JSon</button>
```

```
    #loader {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        z-index: 10000;
    }
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".loader").hide();
        $("#btn").on("click",function () {
            //some code
            $(".loader").show();
            $.getJSON(url, (data) => {
                console.log(data);
              $(".loader").hide();
            });

        })
    })
```

Here is an working example in JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/c017xza4/11/

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.
The #ID is a other drop down list that I have in my form, I didn't past the entire .cshtml file, my bad.
Bottom line I want when the user choose a value from the first ddl to show a loading gif till the getJson populate the second.

Comment: @elhajoui I want something like this https://jsfiddle.net/8heyax0d/ And I want the loader to appear after the #FDescr dropdownlist changes Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/csgbure8/3/ here is what you wanted.

The problem you had is not including the right id on the selector and you should use the on method the other ones are depricated

Comment: Fix it, by just adding the $(".loader").hide(); in $.getJSON scope. Sorry @o elhajoui I miss that. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Great to hear that!